# Caught race condition abuser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, cpanel

The images we uploaded to the site are not showing . When we see the apache error_log file we found the following error,

```
Caught race condition abuser. attacker: 0, victim: 99 open file owner: 99, open file: /var/www/site_prod/current/public/system/banners/8/original/nGGEDx_Ben_Renick_Banner_-_10K_.png, referer: http://prod.site.com/en/get-help/get-help-shipping-standards
```

What could be the reason. We have a rails 4 application with capistrano deployment hosted in centos .

All file/folder permissions have been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have enabled Symlink Race Condition Protection on your server and installed Apache patch on your server and due to that you are getting this issues, You will have to check your file and folder ownership.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Symlink+Race+Condition+Protection

Comment: How can we disable Symlink Race Condition Protection through cpanel? Do we have any option to disable it in cpanel?

Comment: It's not possible to disable it only for single account. You will have to run easyapche on your server to disabled it.